# browserstack and jenkins with cypress

Tags: jenkins, cypress, browserstack

I'm working with BrowserStack and cypress I create a Freestyle project and install the plugin for BrowserStack with the credentials

I'm trying to run with these commands:

```
npm install
browserstack-cypress run --sync
line 3: browserstack-cypress: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

I include browserstack-cypress-cli on the dev-dependecies

Can somebody helps me?

Answer (score 0):

Install the BrowserStack Cypress cli using the below command
npm install -g browserstack-cypress-cli

Attaching the documentation link for reference
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/cypress